OOM invoked regularly by PHP-FPM
I'm using EC2 instance t4g.micro which is arm64, with 1gb ram of the latest ubuntu.
I'm using nginx with PHP-FPM for upload and convert pictures using latest image.intervention with GD.
My PHP_FPM configuration:
pm = static
pm.max_children = 1
pm.max_requests = 300

And php.ini:
max_execution_time = 5
memory_limit = 100M
opcache.enable = 1
opcache.jit_buffer_size = 50M
opcache.jit = 1255

And yet I keep on getting those messages from time to time on my syslog:
Out of memory: Killed process 510 (php-fpm8.3) total-vm:490452kB, anon-rss:273404kB, file-rss:2944kB, shmem-rss:3840kB, UID:1001 pgtables:708kB oom_score_adj:0
Out of memory: Killed process 510 (php-fpm8.3) total-vm:499780kB, anon-rss:282508kB, file-rss:2944kB, shmem-rss:3968kB, UID:1001 pgtables:720kB oom_score_adj:0
Out of memory: Killed process 20481 (php-fpm8.3) total-vm:495800kB, anon-rss:272472kB, file-rss:2944kB, shmem-rss:3456kB, UID:1001 pgtables:708kB oom_score_adj:0
Out of memory: Killed process 24725 (php-fpm8.3) total-vm:465556kB, anon-rss:247920kB, file-rss:2944kB, shmem-rss:1664kB, UID:1001 pgtables:648kB oom_score_adj:0
Out of memory: Killed process 24732 (php-fpm8.3) total-vm:458888kB, anon-rss:240892kB, file-rss:2816kB, shmem-rss:3456kB, UID:1001 pgtables:624kB oom_score_adj:0
Out of memory: Killed process 24739 (php-fpm8.3) total-vm:458280kB, anon-rss:240372kB, file-rss:2816kB, shmem-rss:3456kB, UID:1001 pgtables:628kB oom_score_adj:0

Sometimes it cause my instance to not respond at all ,not even to SSH, and the CPU reach to 60% precent on AWS monitor and stay there till I manually click on restart instance several times which might cause hard restart.
My php script is simple, takes post image file, convert it and save, using image.intervention functions only, no error are thrown.
The OOM killed might happened once a week..
I tried tuning my configuration to the lowest possible, decreasing pm.max_requests is not a solution for me.
All I want is to avoid OOM intervention, control php to kill request that absorb to much memory before it crushes PHP-FPM.
I already modified PHP-FPM service to restart itself on failure, but sometimes it crushes the whole ubuntu system with high CPU and makes it not responding to anything which is what I must avoid in the first place.
Could it be a leak on php arm specific instance that x86 might avoid?
How can I stable my instance?

Do you have swap? free will tell you.  If not, you need between 1xRAM and 2xRAM. Swap space must be contiguous, not fragmented. Read man mkswap fallocate  filefrag swapon fstab.

Are you measuring the memory that's being consumed by your script and it's child processes?  Your symptoms are consistent with the virtual machine's memory being filled up.  Measurements (especially when saved to a graphing system like Grafana or even Ganglia) can show you when the script's real memory consumption doesn't match the assumed consumption.

@waltinator I don't have swap at all, I'm reading about it now and will activate it, but why can't I block PHP-FPM from ever consuming memory more than possible? I don't ever want the system to fully not respond ,waiting for manual restart, I expect the system to kill php much earlier and restart the service.

@SottoVoce I'm not measuring since I can't see it on time, all I have is my syslogs shared here.  the script is simple sync php file using known library image.intervention, I guess it's a memory leak because php would have catch it earlier by the memory_limit, but since it is a child process it's up to PHP-FPM and the os to kill it.

Read `man ulimit``

@waltinator as for the swap file, I'm using fallocate to create a double size ram file, mkswap it, enabling it using swapon, then make it permanent with fstab and vm.swappiness=0. but none of which ensure swap file is contiguous, filefrag only tell if it is fragmented, what do I miss? using ulimit -v for limiting PHP-FPM user, only takes a fixed size. what makes the OS to not respond at all? why can't it kill the process long before it stuck? how does it happened?

This is not a conversational site, nor a tutorial site.
